# Exportin XML files with limited record set with SSIS

Tags: xml, ssis, foreach-loop-container

I have table for  +2000 rows. Each row represent a instance in XML file I have managed to generate:

[image]

Output:

[image]

The need is to select 500 rows at a time, generate XML and save it as a file into selected folder. The naming of the file should be dynamic eg. file_name_20171128**165412** and the next one file_name_20171128**165520**

Tried to solve with For each loop with variable parameters but not getting it right - also need ideas for saving and naming the XML files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't use for loops too often but you can do this:

set the following variables:

```
loopcounter int set initial value = 0
rowsprocessed int set initial value = 500
sql string
```

1. Add a for loop container
2. Set the eval expression to  @rowsprocessed <500 (This will make the last loop when processing less than 500 records
3. Set assign expression to @loopcounter = @loopcounter +1
4. Assign expression to sql to:

   ";with cte as
   (
   select *,ROW_NUMBER() over (order by [the primary key]) rn
   from [your table]
   )
   select *
   from cte
   where rn between " + cstr(@loopcounter*500+1) +" and "+cstr((@loopcounter+1)*500)
5. Use @sql as your extract query
6. Add a Row Count to dataflow and assign value to rowsprocessed.

Hope this helps.

Comment: as for naming the file,I don't understand your logic but maybe: fname = "base" + cstr(year(getdate()) + right("0"+cstr(month(getdate()),2)+right"0" + cstr(day(getdate()),2) + cstr(@loopcounter+1)